# Testing URL Params in Angular Unit Test

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, testbed

I am attempting to test for a string contained within URL parameters. In my typescript file I have the method:

```
 checkURLParams() {
    if (this.route.parent) {
      this.route.parent.params.subscribe((params) => {
        if (params['view'] === 'view') {
          this.form.disable();
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

The test should ensure that when the parameters contain the string 'view', the form should be disabled.

Currently in my spec file I have:

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
   
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit('test', fakeAsync(() => {

    // Arrange


    // Act
    component.checkURLParams();


    // Assert
    expect(component.form.disabled).toBeTruthy();
  }));
```

I have seen some solutions to different ways of testing URL parameters but cannot find a way to mock the URL parameters in the test to contain 'view' in order to disable the form. What would be the best approach to solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar case where i needed test URLs and results.

```js
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let component: AppComponent;
  let location: Location;
  let router: Router;

  beforeEach(() => {
    location = TestBed.inject(Location);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);

    fixture.ngZone.run(() => {
      router.initialNavigation();
    });
  });

  it('test', waitForAsync(() => {
      fixture.ngZone.run(async () => {
        await router.navigate(['yourUrl/With/Params']);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        component.checkURLParams();
        expect(component.form.disabled).toBeTruthy();
      });
    })
  );
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! What did you have in your setup beforeEach?